# Как программно узнать размыто ли изображение?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit, fft

нужно узнать размыто ли изображение,  я знаю что можно узнать с помощью FFT но как написать в коде, на swift не понимаю никак, поделитесь пожалуйста ссылкой на код, или пожалуйста напишите код сюда, заранее благодарю